# How to merge HTML input box(Subscribe box) and a button with responsive? (sample images attached)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to web designing and i m trying to create template which is task given to me ...i want to create a subscribe input textbox with button. i put some screenshot and code of my file.please help me to resolve

```
   <section style="background-color: #ea6153">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="subscribe-content-text">
                            <h4>IF YOU WANT DAILY UPDATE OF OUR PRODUCT THEN JOIN AND SUBSCRIBE OUR NEWS LETTER</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="input-group subscribe-form">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="input-form" placeholder="Your Email here">
                        <span><button class="btn subscribe-btn" type="button">SUBSCRIBE</button></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        <section>


    This is my CSS file:


    .subscribe-content-text
    {
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: Roboto, Serif;
        color: #ffffff;
        text-align: left;
        margin-top: 75px;
        margin-bottom:70px;
    }
    .subscribe-form
    {
        margin-top: 64px;
    }
    #input-form
    {
        border: 1px solid white;
        border-radius: 0px;
        background-color: #ea6153;
        color: #ffffff;

    }
    input[type="text"]
    {
        color: #ffffff;

    }
    input::-webkit-input-placeholder
    {
        color:#ffffff !important;
        font-size: 14px !important;
        font-family: Roboto, Serif !important;
    }
    input::-moz-placeholder
    {
        color: #ffffff !important;
        font-size: 14px !important;
        font-family: Roboto, Serif !important;
    }

    .subscribe-btn
    {
       position: absolute;
       background-color: #ffffff;
       color: #ea6153;
       font: 24px bold;
       font-family: Roboto, Serif;
       font-weight: bold;
       border-style: none;
       border-radius: inherit;
    }
    [This screenshot which i need to create in html responsive][1]


    [This screenshot which i made in html**strong text**][2]


      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3qze.png
      [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGvfr.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go with below link or code may be it can help you.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/neqh81tj/4/)

HTML Code -

```
<section style="background-color: #ea6153">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="subscribe-content-text">
          <h4>IF YOU WANT DAILY UPDATE OF OUR PRODUCT THEN JOIN AND SUBSCRIBE OUR NEWS LETTER</h4>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group subscribe-form">
          <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="input-form" placeholder="Your Email here">
          <button class="btn subscribe-btn" type="button">SUBSCRIBE</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <section>
```

CSS Code -

```
.subscribe-content-text {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Roboto, Serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 75px;
  margin-bottom: 70px;
}

.subscribe-form {
  margin-top: 64px;
  position: relative;
}

#input-form {
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background-color: #ea6153;
  color: #ffffff;
  position:relative;
  padding: 0px 30% 0px 10px;
}

input[type="text"] {
  color: #ffffff;
}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #ffffff !important;
  font-size: 14px !important;
  font-family: Roboto, Serif !important;
}

input::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #ffffff !important;
  font-size: 14px !important;
  font-family: Roboto, Serif !important;
}

.subscribe-btn {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #ea6153;
  font: 24px bold;
  font-family: Roboto, Serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top:3px;
}
```

Comment: It's my pleasure :) @MeetShah

Answer (score 0):

```css
/*
Contact Form by html-form-guide.com
You can customize all the aspects of the form in this style sheet
All the style elements use form id selector(notice the #contactus). So, including this
stylesheet does not affect the other elements at all!
*/

#contactus fieldset
{
   
   
   border:0px solid #ccc;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-khtml-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;   
}

#contactus legend, h2
{
 font-family : Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 1em;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #333;
}

#contactus label
{
   font-family : Arial, sans-serif;
   font-size:0.8em;
   font-weight: bold;
}

#contactus input[type="text"],textarea
{
  font-family : Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  line-height:140%;
  color : #000; 
  padding : 3px; 
  border : 1px solid #999;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;

}

#contactus input[type="text"]
{
  height:18px;
  width:120px;
  
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
   border-radius: 5px;   
  
}

#contactus #scaptcha
{
  width:60px;
  height:18px;
}

#contactus input[type="submit"]
{
   width:100px;
   height:30px;
   padding-left:0px;
   
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
   border-radius: 5px;   
}

#contactus textarea
{
  height:120px;
  width:110px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
   border-radius: 8px;  
}

#contactus input[type="text"]:focus,textarea:focus
{
  color : #009;
  border : 1px solid #990000;
  background-color : #ffff99;
  font-weight:bold;
}

#contactus .containerF
{ 
   
}

#contactus .error
{
   font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; 
   font-size: 0.7em;
   color: #900;
   background-color : #ffff00;
}

#contactus fieldset#antispam
{
   padding:2px;
   border-top:1px solid #EEE;
   border-left:0;
   border-right:0;
   border-bottom:0;
   
}

#contactus fieldset#antispam legend
{
   font-family : Arial, sans-serif;
   font-size: 0.8em;
   font-weight:bold;
   color:#333;   
}

#contactus .short_explanation
{
 font-family : Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 0.6em;
 color: #FFF;
}

/* spam_trap: This input is hidden. This is here to trick the spam bots*/
#contactus .spmhidip
{
   display:none;
   width:10px;
   height:3px;
}
#fg_crdiv
{
   font-family : Arial, sans-serif;
   font-size: 0.3em;
   opacity: .2;
   -moz-opacity: .2;
   filter: alpha(opacity=20);   
}
#fg_crdiv p
{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: This has always worked for me. let me know if you have any questions about it.